# Import-csv command to read a CSV from Document Library is giving error

Tags: 2013, powershell, import, csv

I am trying to read a CSV file from a SharePoint 2013 Document Library. I am using following Powershell command for this.

```
Import-csv "\\ServerName\sites\SiteName\MyDocumentLibrary\MyCSVFile.csv"
```

But, I am getting this error `The network name cannot be found.`.

Can somebody let me know, what i am missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$FilePath = "http://ServerName/sites/SiteName/MyDocumentLibrary/MyCSVFile.csv"
$localPath = "C:\temp\test.csv" #Make sure temp folder exists
$wc = New-Object System.Net.Webclient
$wc.DownloadFile($FilePath, $localPath)
$list = Import-Csv $localPath
```

Comment: That's a good alternative method. But, does this imply that we can't read a .csv file directly from a document library(without making a local copy of it).

Comment: I think you can do if you have mapped the library using a Network Drive.

Comment: I am getting `Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."`

Comment: Add this before downloadfile `$wc.UseDefaultCredentials = $true`

Comment: Yes, just figured that out....now this method is working for me. But i am still looking how can i use the UNC path to read it directly from the Document library, as mentioned [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b4a52fb7-87b4-4f73-97fc-2918d420f0eb/read-csv-file-in-sp2010-document-library). Without even using a Network Drive.

Comment: If you read, its says the path should be in WebDav format. To setup that https://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/storage-products-c76537/sharepoint-c68886/establish-a-webdav-connection-to-a-sharepoint-site-a722056.html.. you are creating a network drive.

Comment: Have you tried `Import-Csv "http://ServerName/sites/SiteName/MyDocumentLibrary/MyCSVFile.csv"`?

Comment: It errors out saying `Import-csv : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'http' does not exist.`

Comment: Ok that means either the file should in local path or network path